# Dynamically Loaded Script is undefined after load

Tags: javascript

When adding a script loaded dynamically, I can access main object during execution but once the page is loaded, if I try to access that from console, it throws undefined. For example,

```
 var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
 js.onload = ()=> { /* do something when script loads */}
 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
```

This should ideally append FB object to window, and it does that during execution of page. I can access `window.FB` while the aforesaid JS is executing, but once the page is loaded (and I know that js.onload is also executed), I can't access FB.someOperation.

What is the solution to ensure that dynamically added script is always available (even after page has loaded)

Comment: `onLoad` should be `onload`

Answer (score 1):

Remember to [double check the property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload).

`onLoad` should be `onload` (all lowercase).

```js
var d = document;
var id = 'hello';
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
js = d.createElement('script');
js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";

js.onload = () => {
//   ^--------------------------- note the lowercase 'l'
  console.log('hello world');
};

fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
```

```html
<script></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to using [jQuery.getScript()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) for `dynamic` as you've mentioned.

Ex:

```
var func = function () {
    console.log('do this without the script');

    console.log('geting script...');

    $.getScript( "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
          console.log('script is loaded...');

          console.log( data ); // Data returned
          console.log( textStatus ); // Success
          console.log( jqxhr.status ); // 200
          console.log( "Load was performed." );
    });
};

func();
```